# I want to show a link in yii Cgridview with other url

Tags: php, yii

I want to show a link in Cgridview with other url like http://example.com/video.flv.

I have tried this in CGridview

```
       array(
        'header'=>'Video Url',
        'name'  => 'video_url',
        'value' => 'CHtml::link($data->title,$data->video_url, array("target"=>"_blank"))',
        'type'  => 'raw',
         ),
```

but when I click on this link it is stay under my site but I want to go that url which I have saved in

```
$data->video_url like example.com/video.flv
```

Can you help me please?

Comment: Sounds like you're missing `http://` before the URL, so it thinks it's a relative path.

Comment: now add in model validation rules just this.
array('video_url', 'url', 'defaultScheme' => 'http'),

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this send it to controller action as shown below ex

```
array(
            'name'=>'URL',
            'type'=>'raw',
            'value' => 'CHtml::link($data->url,Yii::app()->createUrl("listing/doctoryogacommon/UrlProcessing",array("url"=>$data->url)),array("target"=>"_blank"))',
      ),
```

And in your controller action use as shown

```
public function actionUrlProcessing(){
        $this->redirect($_GET['url']);
    }
```

Comment: It's a solution, but I don't see why a simple outsourced URL needs to go through an action (unless you're actively trying to use that for stats or to filter out reported URLs)

Comment: @ChenAsraf I have used your solution, also Ninad give me solution for other issue. so thank you and also Ninad too.